# VBA weekday functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro which runs a report at the end of each weekday.  However on fridays & the last day of each month, it fails to select the data for the next upcoming monday or first day of month. When the report in run from Mon-Thurs, it works as it should.  I wonder if it is a logic error. Below is the code in the Macro list. Any suggestions would be great.

```
Sub combine()

Call Macro1

Call Macro2

Call Macro3

Call Macro4

Call Macro9

Call Macro5

PtbC = Now()

PtbC = DateSerial(Year(PtbC), Month(PtbC), Day(PtbC + 1))

daycount = Day(PtbC) + 35

ShipWeek = Date + 47

Call Macro11

Call MacroLED

Call Macro6

Call Macro10

Call Macro12

Call Macro13

Call Macro14

Call Macro7

Call Macro8
```

Comment: `PtbC = DateSerial(Year(PtbC), Month(PtbC), Day(PtbC + 1))` could just be  `PtbC = Application.WorkDay(Date, 1)`.

Comment: Where in your code do you use the `PtbC` variable? It does not look like any of your calls use it? And where do you use the `daycount` and ShipWeek`? It doesn't look like you've included enough information and code to spot where the issue might be